# What was the most advanced form of Mathematics in the times of Copernicus?

Tags: math-history

I often became amazed watching those Discovery channel documentaries of the 90's regarding advances in science in the times of the Renaissance and I always wondered what kinds of mathematical tools were available to western scientists to perform their computations?.

Since logarithms were not "invented" what instruments did they used?. I had read in Wikipedia that Prosthaphaeresis were used by navigators to ease their calculations. But other than these tables or some trigonometric functions, what did they used. Abacus? the Soroban or Suanpan?.

Did astronomers, physicists, mathematicians understood functions as we know today?. I mean as a wave. I doubt they did have a cartesian system at hand since I'm referring to the 16th century.

Is there a place where I can read about this, let's say a timeline or a short summary?.

Comment: Yes, they used trigonometry.

Comment: And no: the modern concept of function started to apepra in 18th Century : Leibniz, Euler, Bernoulli.

Comment: Of course, Cartesian coordinate systems,(due to [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) around 1650, was not available to [Copernicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_Copernicus) : around 1500.

Comment: You can see [16th Century Math](http://www.storyofmathematics.com/16th.html), [17th Century Math](http://www.storyofmathematics.com/17th.html), [A History of Mathematics : The Renaissance](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_History_of_Mathematics/Modern_Europe/The_Renaissance) and linked articles.

Comment: The concept of a function in India existed earlier than that .( Murthy?Bamglore ? ) I cant get the source now, had one book with me. earlier

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for your input. But a more elaborate answer would be appreciated. My question was among all the mathematics at its disposal what was used to ease calculations?.

Comment: @Narasimham It looks interesting but was that available in the west at the times of Copernicus?.

Comment: The information transfer /exchange.. of history are matters of research perhaps.

Comment: See [Nicolaus Copernicus](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Copernicus.html): "While a student in Kraków, Copernicus purchased a copy of the Latin translation of Euclid's *Elements* published in Venice in 1482, a copy of the second edition of the *Alfonsine Tables* (which gives planetary theory and eclipses) printed in Venice in 1492, and Regiomontanus's *Tables of Directions* (a work on spherical astronomy) published in Augsburg in 1490. Remarkably Copernicus's copies of these works, signed by him, are still preserved."